# Sphinx search filter to handle arrays

Tags: arrays, filter, sphinx

I have a database of objects which have each been assigned to multiple categories. I am using sphinx search to search the products but would also like to filter the results to only objects that match an array of categories.

Comment: does the product have to match any category or all categories in the array? what if the product is in categories x, y, z, w but the filter is limited to x, y, z?

Comment: it needs to match ANY 1 of the passed categories, not all.

Comment: Basically, if it matches one or more of the categories, then retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use SetFilter exclude option to solve this.

For example you have following category IDs:1,2,3,4,5
and you need to search in 1 or 3 category.

```
$sphinx->SetFilter("category_id", (2,4,5), true);
```

code above will exclude from search categories 2,4 and 5,
so in our case search will perform only in category 1 and 3.